# jquery mobile 1.4 alpha 2, icon with button

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, icons

I would like to have an icon on the left and a text on the right, without using the button markup but rather using div or span.

i dont see how to do that in the [doc](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-alpha.2/demos/widgets/icons/), i tried doing that :

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">Left</a>
```

replacing the a tag with div or span but it doesnt show any icon

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eVaGisA/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

On my end this:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">my text</a>
```

as well as this

```
<div href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">my text</div>
```

produce a button with icon. Tried both Firefox and Chrome. See here: http://jsbin.com/eVaGisA/5/ (**UPDATE** link had stopped working , should be ok now)

[image: snippet output]

You do need the `data-role="button"` markup. If you read the [documentation here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/data-attributes.html), it says:

> Input-based buttons, links in toolbars and button elements are
>   auto-enhanced, no data-role required.

Thus, a `div` and `a` element do require it.

**Update 2** - case of applying custom icons to a collapsible header

For collapsible header, jquery mobile provides data-collapsed-icon and data-expanded-icon attributes. Use case is as:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" >
   <h3>Header1</h3>
   <p>Content 1</p>
   <p>Content 2</p>
</div>
```

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gk2Bx/)

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, but that doesnt show any icon to me (latest versions of firefox and chrome). And i dont want to have a button but just a text and an icon nearby (left or right i dont really care)

Comment: The link wasn't working - updated and included a snapshot, pls see above. What do you mean you don' want a button? If I understood correctly, you are avoiding `<input type='button'>` and `<button>` but want to achieve a button like effect with `div` / `a`? If so - my example works and you need to include the data-role=button attribute if you want to achieve this appearance. If not - please elaborate.

Comment: thanks for your new jsbin. I know how to do that as i use jqm for a while now but this is not i would like, i'll elaborate further : i dont want the button like effect but just the icon (using the icon widget which handles svg / png according to your browser) and the text nearby. It will be embedded in a collapsible header. I tried a lot of things to remove the button like effect and trying to keep icon and text (without the link styling) but nothing works till now and there is nothing in the doc about it.

Comment: Perhaps include this information in the question itself so other's don't miss it. Could you also provide a snippet of the collapsible header?

Comment: If you're using standard headers - I included an example with custom icons.